# Mixing relative and absolute imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a project with the following structure:

```
|-- package-1
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module1.py
|   |-- module1_scheduler.py
|
|-- package-2
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- module2.py
|   |-- module2_scheduler.py
|   |-- subpackage2
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- module21.py
|       |-- module22.py
|
|-- package-3
    |-- module3.py
```

For reasons that will become clear I'll have to share the imports from inside some of the modules. So:

### module3.py

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))
import importlib
module1 = importlib.import_module("package-1.module1")
module2 = importlib.import_module("package-2.module2")

result1 = module1.some_function(a,b,c)
result2 = module2.other_function(d,e,f)
```

### module2.py

```
from . subpackage2 import module21
from . subpackage2 import module22
```

### module2_scheduler.py

```
import module2 as m2
```

Now there are two different cases that I run my software.

In the first case, I run `module3.py`, and it runs just fine.

But in the second case, I call the scheduler `module2_scheduler.py`, and it returns an error with trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/app/package-2/module2_scheduler.py", line 1, in <module>
    import module2 as m2
  File "/opt/app/package-2/module2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . subpackage2 import module21
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

If I remove the relative imports inside `module2.py`, and use absolute imports(eg. `import subpackage2.module21 as m21`), the scheduler `module2_scheduler.py` works just fine. But then I can't use `module3.py`, because it returns `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module21'`.

So I'm stuck in this position where I need to use both relative and absolute imports, but it results to the above `ImportError` mentioned. Any ideas are welcome. Thank you.